# contact form doesnt send mail

Tags: php, jquery, forms, contacts

I need help with this contact form. I've tried everything possible to send it but it's not working. When you fill all the details in on the form, and press send, the form clears but that's it, nothing else happens. I check the email box the details should go to but theres nothing there. I have changed the email address on jQuery as I'm suppose to plus I've checked the code several times but nothing has worked.

```
<form>
  <br>
  <div class="form-row">
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post" id="reused_form">
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>

    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
      <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
    </div>
    <div id="error_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none; ">
      <h3>Error</h3>
      Sorry there was an error sending your form.
    </div>
```

```
$(function(){
  function after_form_submitted(data){
    if(data.result == 'success'){
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();
    }else{
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

      jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val){
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function(){
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
        if(label){
          $btn.prop('type','submit' );
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label','');
        }
      });

    }//else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);

    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function(){
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type','button' );
      $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
      $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json'
    });

   });
 });
```

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;


$pp = new FormHandler();

$validator = $pp->getValidator();
$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);
$validator->field('email')->isEmail();
$validator->field('message')->maxLength(6000);


$pp->requireReCaptcha();
$pp->getReCaptcha()-
>initSecretKey('');


$pp->sendEmailTo('marcogianni.webdev@gmail.com'); // ← Your email here
//  $pp->sendEmailTo(['someone@gmail.com',
'another@gmail.com','more@gmail.com']); (for more than one email addresses

echo $pp->process($_POST);`
```

Comment: Seems like you have two nested `<form>` tags... This is invalid.

Comment: you were right, thanks

Comment: In fact, the form still doesn't work. I removed the form tags. any suggestions? do you need to see more code?

Comment: Well... At least one form tag is needed with an id `reused_form`, because that is the submit handler trigger: `$('#reused_form').submit(function(e){` and because you use `.serialize()`.